# Causal, anticausal, BIBO stable

Tags: signal

I have a hard time defining those impulse responses, are they causal, anti-causal, BIBO stable ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: `I have a hard time defining those impulse responses` is not a useful description of a problem ... please describe what you understand and what you do not understand .... add all info to the question ... **do not use comments**

Comment: "causal, anti-causal, BIBO stable", why don't you start by defining those terms, and then you can work from there.